# Angular 2: Simple AddClass with delay

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, ionic2

i try to animate a list of items in angular 2, but for some reason this dont work at all.

All i do is get a HTMLCollection with getClass and then add a class on a timeout.

```
    platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
        let workoutItems: HTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("my-workout-item");

        for (var i = 0; workoutItems[i]; i++) {
            workoutItems[i].classList.add("fadeInUp");

            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("test");
                workoutItems[i].classList.add("fadeInUp");

            }, 1000);
        }
```

Iam not sure why this code dont work. Can anyone help me to bring this to life?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you have tried and where you failed.

Comment: Usage of direct element manipulation is strongly not recommended in angular2, did you consider doing it from within the framework?

Comment: Yes, but i am relative new to angular2.

Whats the best way to archive something like this?

Comment: check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to write that :

```
workoutItems[i].className += " fadeInUp";
```

Instead of :

```
workoutItems[i].classList.add("fadeInUp");
```

?